# Refresh object tag after changing param value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, 3d, autodesk

I have object tag rendering a DWF file using the following code:

```
<div id="canvas" style="width: 400px; height: 400px; border: 1px solid black;">
    <object id="ADViewer" classid="clsid:A662DA7E-CCB7-4743-B71A-D817F6D575DF" border="1"
            style="width: 400px; height: 400px;" viewastext>
            <param name="Src" value="http://gis-darwish/StructuresWebViewer/DWF/PP1.dwf" />
        </object>
</div>
```

i want to change the value of the param tag with a new url then refresh the object tag.

i have changed the url with the following code:

```
$("#ADViewer param[name=Src]").attr('value', url);
```

the url changed but the object tag still with its old state.

can anyone tell me how to refresh the object tag without creating the whole object html again.

Answer (score 0):

you can use cookies to do that.
you can store your "url" in cookie and after loading page you can set the value by retrieving value from cookie

Comment: no. you have to again set that value after refresh with the help of cookie

Comment: can you clarify your answer ?

Comment: store your url in cookie with some name. after refresh, get that cookie value and assign it again to your param tag